# Load Doubleword Pseudoinstruction in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to understand the ld (load double word) pseudo instruction in MIPS32.  How could I translate something like:

```
ld $t1, 0($t0)
```

into an executable set of MIPS instructions without destroying the value of $t0?  I understand that for a 32-bit quantity I should use a lui instruction (for the first 16 bits) followed by an ori instruction (for the last 16 bits), but I do not understand how to extend this logic for a 64-bit quantity.  Thank you!

**Edited to specify that I am using MIPS32, not MIPS64**

Comment: _"I understand that for a 32-bit quantity I should use a lui instruction (for the first 16 bits) followed by an ori instruction (for the last 16 bits)"_ Huh? `ld` loads from memory, which is very different from loading an immediate. If you want to see the actual instructions generated by the assembler for an `ld`, just open a source file containing an `ld` instruction in SPIM.

Comment: Wait just one hot second!  Could I just use a lui instruction and then the ori instruction and then use add to add the value of $t0 to itself?!

Comment: Also note that `ld` is an actual instruction on the MIPS64 architecture. You haven't specified which architecture you're talking about, but I'm assuming MIPS32.

Comment: Yes MIPS32, I am sorry for not specifying.

Comment: Could you explain what it is that you're actually trying to achieve, without focusing on any particular instruction?

Comment: Basically as @Jester pointed out, ld does the same thing for MIPS64 as li does for MIPS32.  At least that's how I understand it.  But in MIPS32 how is it possible to load a 64-bit quantity into a register?  ld is of the form ld registerdest, address and the instruction is supposed to load the 64-bit quantity at address into registers registerdest AND registerdest + 1.

Comment: _"ld does the same thing for MIPS64 as li does for MIPS32"_. No, `ld` loads a doubleword from memory. It is the 64-bit counterpart to `lw`. _"in MIPS32 how is it possible to load a 64-bit quantity into a register?"_ It isn't, because the registers are 32-bit.

Comment: That still doesn't explain how I can translate a ld instruction into MIPS32...

Comment: By doing what I suggested in my first comment: _"If you want to see the actual instructions generated by the assembler for an ld, just open a source file containing an ld instruction in SPIM."_

Comment: If you want `ld` you will need to pick two 32 bit registers to load the two halves of the value. As such, you would translate it to something like  `lw $t1, ($t0); lw $t2, 4($t0)`.

Comment: Thank you, @Jester, that makes sense I'll try that.